# How to search for external MySQL data extracts from Joomla 3.2

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla-k2

I have an internal company project that is using Joomla 3.2/K2. We are pulling in external data via the Custom HTML module and including PHP code that extracts data from a MySQL database. The issue is that the search functionality of Joomla does not capture the data that is being extracted.

Is there a way to include external data in a Joomla search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a [plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers#Plugins), the details are on [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) in the [Developer Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Developers). There's even a [Plugin Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aPlugin_Development) with all relevant articles listed.

Joomla has two types of search plugin, the older standard `/plugins/search/` and the relatively (since 2.5) Smart Search, which has it's plugins in `/plugins/finder`.

Standard search plugins are relatively easy to write and are described in the [Creating a Search Plug](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_search_plugin) (note this is a landing page from which you select the version of Joomla you're writing for).

[Smart Search](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aSmart_Search) was introduced with the 2.5 line and the [Creating a Smart Search plug-in](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Smart_Search_plug-in) article covers them..

Answer (score 0):

Inside admin you can edit the con.xml line 133; searchExternal = Yes | True will pipe responses through the integrated reg expression conduit.  At that point your session will include all the params +3 which provide artifact binding.  Bind to standard out, this will add the additional mysql cursor results into your answer set for presentation.

Comment: I can't find the string `searchExternal` nor the file `con.xml` anywhere in Joomla 3.2 or K2 2.6.7 can you clarify your answer?